# How to detect if there is an arbitrary document has been signed with opencv

Tags: opencv

I've been tasked with classifying 350k documents into "signed" and "not signed" piles. What is the fastest way to search for something that looks like a human signature with open source tools? To compound the problem, I need to assume each document is unique length and signature location. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are the documents printed, otherwise?

Comment: Yeah, the documents are otherwise printed.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of searching on Google, I have founded [this article of IEEE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4270280). You will need to have an account to be able to read it.

Here is the description:

> Detecting and segmenting free-form objects from cluttered backgrounds
> is a challenging problem in computer vision. Signature detection in
> document images is one classic example and as of yet no reasonable
> solutions have been presented. In this paper, we propose a novel
> multi-scale approach to jointly detecting and segmenting signatures
> from documents with diverse layouts and complex backgrounds. Rather
> than focusing on local features that typically have large variations,
> our approach aims to capture the structural saliency of a signature by
> searching over multiple scales. This detection framework is general
> and computationally tractable. We present a saliency measure based on
> a signature production model that effectively quantifies the dynamic
> curvature of 2D contour fragments. Our evaluation using large real
> world collections of handwritten and machine printed documents
> demonstrates the effectiveness of this joint detection and
> segmentation approach.